# Selecting Rows with Duplicate Data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've got some MySQL tables with redundant data that I need to remove. For example:

```
 id email            date       data...
 1  email1@gmail.com 2012-01-01 my_data
 2  email2@gmail.com 2012-01-01 my_data
 3  email1@gmail.com 2012-01-02 my_data
 4  email1@gmail.com 2012-01-02 my_data   (redundant)
 5  email2@gmail.com 2012-01-02 my_data
```

I need to DELETE the redundant rows, but I'd like to select them first. I found this on StackOverflow, but it requires the email address

```
SELECT * 
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` 
               FROM `my_table` 
               where `email` = 'email1@gmail.com' 
               group by `date` 
               HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

What query can i use like above that does not use the WHERE qualifier in the embedded query so I can do it fall all email addresses?

The query can be a SELECT query. I don't mind removing the rows manually in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: ''''What query can i use like above that does not use the WHERE qualifier in the embedded query so I can do it fall all email addresses? '''By this do u mean all the duplicate ones and just the keep a single copy ??

Comment: Yes, remove all the duplicate rows, but keep the original row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tableName
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT minID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT email, date, MIN(id) minID
        FROM tableNAme
        GROUP BY email, date
    ) x
)
```

- [***SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e29e5/1)

or by using `JOIN`

```
DELETE a 
FROM tableName a
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT minID
            FROM (
                    SELECT email, DATE, MIN(id) minID
                    FROM tableNAme
                    GROUP BY email, DATE
                    ) y
            ) x
            ON a.ID = x.minID
WHERE x.minID IS NULL;
```

- [***SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09732/1)

The following query only `SELECT` duplicated rows for each *email* and *date*

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a
        LEFT JOIN 
       ( 
         SELECT minID
        FROM
        (
          SELECT email, date, MIN(id) minID
          FROM tableNAme
          GROUP BY email, date
        )y
       ) x ON a.ID = x.minID
WHERE x.minID IS NULL
```

- [***SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24977/6)

Comment: John deserves double points because he answered it perfectly and introduced me to SQL Fiddle! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to count the number of occurrences of the date column for each email address in your table:

```
SELECT `email`, `date`, COUNT(*) FROM `my_table` GROUP BY `date`, `email` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| email            | date                | COUNT(*) |
+------------------+---------------------+----------+
| email1@gmail.com | 2012-01-02 00:00:00 |        2 |
+------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: But then I have to do it for every email address.

Comment: @EricCope I made this query output from your sample data, but if you have many emails it would automatically present all emails with count > 1 for every day of operation.  You have to also keep in mind the limit of rows you want to delete, i.e. in the case above you have count of 2, so you can delete only one row, not two(!).  So being on a very safe side, you could rewrite my query as:  

`SELECT email, date, COUNT(*) AS 'count', 
CONCAT('DELETE FROM my_table WHERE email = \'',email,'\' LIMIT ',(COUNT(*) - 1),';') AS 'query'
FROM my_table GROUP BY date, email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`